# unsafe.SizeOf() says any string takes 16 bytes, but how?

Tags: string, go

Simply running `fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(""))` prints 16. Changing the content of the string doesn't affect the outcome.

Can someone explain how where this number (16) come from?

Comment: The [string header](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader) size is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings in Go are represented by [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader) containing a pointer to actual string data and a length of string:

```golang
type StringHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
}
```

`unsafe.Sizeof(s)` will only return the size of `StringHeader` struct but not the pointed data itself. So (in your example) it will be sum of 8 bytes for `Data` and 8 bytes for `Len` making it 16 bytes.